Implementation of an incrementing variable after a specified period of time
I am learning C and implementing a function where a variable is incremented at a certain period of time. However, I have been unable to find a solution that isn't dependent on operating system (pthreads) or ones that are for C++ or C#. Additionally, I am unable to find a way that doesn't use a function like usleep(); because I need to have this running with the rest of the program, not stopping it.
This is the function that I've written so far, but as mentioned I haven't been able to find a solution. There is no code in the main function. I'm using <stdlib.h> and <raylib.h>.
int increment = 0;

void var_increment(){
    // can't find a time based way
    increment += 1;
}


Can you do it the other way round: find an expression that derives the variable's value from elapsed time, when needed?

Since we don't know anything about the rest of your program it will be hard to offer anything other than vague ideas. One would be to create a timestamp for when the next time you want to increment the variable is. In your main program periodically check if the current time is after that timestamp and if it is call the function and set the timestamp to the next time to call it.

@RetiredNinja I should've clarified that the main function is empty (other than function call), this is a new file (added it to post)

Then you need to make your main function not empty. If the main function has no code your program will immediately exit so no increments will be performed. You said "I need to have this running with the rest of the program" so there must be something going on.

It's simply not possible. However, what are you doing with that variable? After some time, you'll be reading it? Make it the other way round: store the start time of your program, and when you want to read that "magically incremented" counter, just look at how much time has elapsed since the program started, and return the correct value calculated from that...

You can use a compile time conditional to check which OS it is being compiled on (e.g. #ifdef (_WIN32) and then include the proper interval timer for that OS. There is no directly portable C timer implementation, unlike e.g. std::chrono for C++ (if fully implemented by the compiler)

There is no good timer or thread support in standard C. The threading support that was introduced with C11 (much too late) doesn't seem to be used by anyone(?).

Raylib provides the following timing-related functions:
void SetTargetFPS(int fps);     // Set target FPS (maximum)
float GetFrameTime(void);       // Get time in seconds for last frame drawn (delta time)
double GetTime(void);           // Get elapsed time in seconds since InitWindow()
int GetFPS(void);               // Get current FPS

In particular, GetTime or GetFrameTime can be used to derive time-based increments.
Here is an example that increments a counter once per second (using very basic delta timing). Additionally, it shows the difference between GetTime (being an offset from InitWindow) and cumulative frame deltas.
#include <raylib.h>

int main(void)
{
    InitWindow(300, 80, "Timing Example");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    float elapsed = 0;
    float timer = 0;
    unsigned counter = 0;
    unsigned frame = 0;

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        float dt = GetFrameTime();
        elapsed += dt;
        timer += dt;

        if (timer >= 1.0f) {
            timer -= 1.0f;
            counter++;
        }

        frame++;

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawText(TextFormat("%d FPS | FRAME %u", GetFPS(), frame), 10, 5, 20, GREEN);
        DrawText(TextFormat("%.2fs", elapsed), 10, 40, 20, BLACK);
        DrawText(TextFormat("%.2fs", timer), 100, 40, 20, BLACK);
        DrawText(TextFormat("%u", counter), 190, 40, 20, BLACK);

        DrawText(TextFormat("%.2fs", GetTime()), 10, 60, 20, BLACK);
        DrawText("~ InitWindow()", 100, 60, 20, BLACK);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}


